# Returning MAX() and MIN() in one query

Tags: rethinkdb

On my RethinkDB 1.16.2-1 on Linux, I have a "products" table that has a "categories" array and a "models" array like this:

```
{
 "name":  "ABC Cable Series" ,
 "categories": [
     "Analog Audio>Instrument>Cables" ,
     "Analog Audio>Microphone Cables"
  ] ,
 "models": [
  {
    "modelCode":  "ABC-1" ,
    "ssp": 11.95 , ...
  } ,
  {
    "modelCode":  "ABC-2" ,
    "ssp": 15.95 , ...
  }
 ]
} , ...
```

I need to get both the minimum and maximum price (ssp) range of models in products that contain the given product category. I can currently get the maximum price like this:

```
r.db("store").table("products").filter(function(prod) {
  return prod("categories").contains(
    function(cat){return cat.match("^Analog Audio>")
  })
}).concatMap(function(doc) {
    return doc("models")("ssp")
}).max()
```

Other than running 2 queries, is there a more efficient way to get both MAX and MIN values in one query?

Comment: On second thought, it might be best to return the list of SSP values and calculate the MAX and MIN within the application (array would contain 200 prices at most). What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you want an object with both values, you can do the following:

```
r.db('test').table('products').filter(function(prod) {
  return prod("categories").contains(
    function(cat){return cat.match("^Analog Audio>")
  })
}).concatMap(function(doc) {
    return doc("models")("ssp")
})
.coerceTo('array')    // Convert Stream to Array
.do(function (rows) { // Pass array to to `.do`
  return {            // Return Object
    max: rows.max(),
    min: rows.min()
  }
})
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. It takes only around 100ms on average to run on my server, which is pretty good considering the complexity of the query. I have to say though the one negative point about using RethinkDB so far is the steep non-intuitive learning curve of ReQL (at least to me). Most developers already know SQL, so I think most would prefer SQL or even an enhanced SQL for this DB which is otherwise awesome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me solve another problem by showing the potential usage of the do() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reduce` (http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/reduce/) to compute both values without converting all data to an array first:

```
r.db("store").table("products").filter(function(prod) {
  return prod("categories").contains(
    function(cat){return cat.match("^Analog Audio>")
  })
}).map(function(doc) {
    return {
      min: doc("models")("ssp").min(),
      max: doc("models")("ssp").max()
    }
}).reduce(function (le, ri) {
    return {
      min: r.expr([le("min"), ri("min")]).min(),
      max: r.expr([le("max"), ri("max")]).max()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. However, even after fixing the missing curly-bracket at the end, I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Sorry about that. The problem was that I named one of the function arguments in the reduction function `r`, which masked the `r` module that I use for `r.expr`. I corrected it in my post.

Comment: No problem, thanks Daniel. A quick one: What is the difference between:  

return prod("categories").contains(
    function(cat){return cat.match("^Analog Audio>")
  }) 

and 

return prod("categories").contains(r.row.match("^Analog Audio>"))

Comment: Those two syntaxes are mostly equivalent.
`r.row` has the limitation that you cannot use it in a place that's nested. E.g. `table.map(r.row('categories').contains(r.row('cat').match('...')))` isn't allowed, because for the second `r.row` inside of `contains` it's not clear whether it applies to the documents in table or to the elements in `categories` of the current document.
In that case RethinkDB will give you an error and you need to use the function syntax. Otherwise it doesn't matter which one you use.